# What is the difference between @Scope (BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE) and @Scope (“prototype”)?

Tags: java, spring

Does the annotation `@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` have any advantages or differences compared to the annotation `@Scope("prototype")`?

Comment: `BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE` is a constant with the value `"prototype"`, so they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do the same thing meaning you can interchange them and shows no difference in behavior.

> Does the annotation @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE) have any advantages?

Advantage I can think of are when you use the pre-defined constants is you have an advantage of avoiding *typos* and saving your time instead of declaring string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Both expressions are equivalents, [`BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html#SCOPE_PROTOTYPE) is a constant in the [`ConfigurableBeanFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableBeanFactory.html) interface with the text ["prototype"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.2.4.RELEASE/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableBeanFactory.java#L60-L65) that is used in the [`BeanDefinition` interface](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.2.4.RELEASE/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.java#L51-L57):

```
/**
 * Scope identifier for the standard prototype scope: {@value}.
 * <p>Note that extended bean factories might support further scopes.
 * @see #setScope
 * @see ConfigurableBeanFactory#SCOPE_PROTOTYPE
 */
String SCOPE_PROTOTYPE = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE;
```

As suggested @santossh-kumhar, the main advantage is that using the constant `SCOPE_PROTOTYPE` instead of the text `"prototype"` is more typo safe.

Comment: BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE is a constant in the ConfigurableBeanFactory interface.`is not exactly correct`. BeanDefinition itself is an interface and has BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE constant declared. ConfigurableBeanFactory is other interface which also has the scopes declared as constants.

Comment: @SantosshKumhar I updated the answer with the reference. The value used by the `BeanDefinition` interface is defined in the `ConfigurableBeanFactory` interface. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.2.4.RELEASE/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.java#L51-L57